# FeatureLayer creating in javascript ArcGIS API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I got the [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/fl/fl_ondemand.html) called "Feature Layer with ONDEMAND mode" in the ArcGIS for js resource center. This example just adds layer with rivers to the map.

I want to use my own features instead of using features from the featureService like in this example. In order to do this I need to use another constructor of FeatureLayer so I modified the code like this:

```
  function initOperationalLayer(map) {

    var featureCollection = {
        layerDefinition: {
          "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
          "fields": [
          {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID"
          },
          {
            "name": "text",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
          },
          {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
          },
          {
            "name": "Shape",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeGeometry"
          }
          ]
        },
        featureSet: 
        [
        {   OBJECTID : 1, 
            text : 'a', 
            address : 'b', 
            Shape :  new esri.geometry.Point(-80.12468662, 40.42756484, map.spatialReference)
        }
        ]
    };
    var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
        mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND
    });

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    map.infoWindow.resize(150,105);
    mapLayers.push(featureLayer);  //this client side map layer is the maps graphics layer
  }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I got errors like "TypeError: _19c is undefined in utils.xd.js(line 14)". It is obfuscated code so i can't understand what't the problem.
Any ideas?

---

The right code is the following one:

```
    var jsonFS = {
        "displayFieldName": "Name",
        "fieldAliases": {
            "Name": "Name"
        },
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 4326
        },
        "fields": [{
            "name": "Name",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "Name",
            "length": 255
        }],
        "features": [{
            "attributes": {
                "Name": "CHINA: YUNNAN PROVINCE; VIETNAM: HANOI"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -10602460.248958504,
                "y": 4716882.997019428
            }
        }]
    };
    var fs = new esri.tasks.FeatureSet(jsonFS);

    var featureCollection = {
        layerDefinition: {
          "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
          "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Name",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "Name"
          }
          ]
        },
        featureSet: fs
    };

var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
        mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND
    });
```

Comment: does this code work in another mode like MODE_SNAPSHOT?

Comment: No, nothing helps. I tried also to use esri.FeatureSet class instead of this array. I always have errors.

Comment: Do you have a a public link to the code you are trying to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'featureCollection' expects a 'features' attribute which is a FeatureSet, and not a featureSet attribute like you are doing:

```
var featureCollection = {
    layerDefinition: {
      "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
      "fields": [
          {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID"
          },
          {
            "name": "text",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
          },
          {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
          }
      ]
    },
    features: 
    [
        {
            "attributes": {
                OBJECTID : 1, 
                text : 'a', 
                address : 'b', 
            },
            "geometry": { "x": -80.12468662, "y": 40.42756484 }
        }
    ]
};
```

For future debugging, I suggest copying the ESRI obfuscated code, and making it more readable by using [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).  Then just search for the error (in my case error was with variable _190).  That should help you out with figuring out where and why the error occurs.

Comment: Not exactly but more or less right, thank you for the JS Beautifier - I'm new in js so didn't know about this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try moving the spatial reference in the layer definition:

```
...
  "spatialReference" : {
    "wkid" : 4326
  }
...
```

And adding quotes around field names and values, and defining the geometry JSON style:

```
...  
{   
    "OBJECTID" : 1, 
    "text" : "a", 
    "address" : "b", 
    "geometry" : {
      "x" : -80.12468662,
      "y" : 40.42756484
    }
 }
...
```

I got inspired by JSON response to querying a feature service e.g.: http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Earthquakes/Since_1970/MapServer/0/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=MAGNITUDE%3E7&time=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=&f=pjson

Good luck.

Comment: it is not this way you described, but anyway thank you for this json - it helped me to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's expecting the alias? Give it a shot.

```
...
"fields": [
          {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias": "ID"
          },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

esri json to feature layer

Lots of api change over years. 
In 2018, you do this.

example arcgis rest api request url:

```
http://xxxx.com/xxx/rest/services/Maps_and_Indices/MapServer/2/query?f=pjson&returnCountOnly=false&outFields=*&outSR=4326&where=DISTRICT%20=%20%27129B149%27%20or%20TILE_NAME%20=%20%27129B149%27%20or%20TOOLTIP%20=%20%27129B149%27%20or%20NLA_URL%20=%20%27129B149%27
```

decode URL:

```
 http://xxxx.com/xxx/rest/services/Maps_and_Indices/MapServer/2/query?f=pjson&returnCountOnly=false&outFields=*&outSR=4326&where=DISTRICT = '129B149' or TILE_NAME = '129B149' or TOOLTIP = '129B149' or NLA_URL = '129B149'
```

data: any arcgis rest api return (response)

example (data) :

```
            {
             "displayFieldName": "TILE_NAME",
             "fieldAliases": {
              "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
              "DISTRICT": "DISTRICT",
              "TILE_NAME": "TILE_NAME",
              "TOOLTIP": "TOOLTIP",
              "NLA_URL": "NLA_URL"
             },
             "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
             "spatialReference": {
              "wkid": 4326,
              "latestWkid": 4326
             },
             "fields": [
              {
               "name": "OBJECTID",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
               "alias": "OBJECTID"
              },
              {
               "name": "DISTRICT",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "DISTRICT",
               "length": 16
              },
              {
               "name": "TILE_NAME",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "TILE_NAME",
               "length": 32
              },
              {
               "name": "TOOLTIP",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "TOOLTIP",
               "length": 66
              },
              {
               "name": "NLA_URL",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "NLA_URL",
               "length": 78
              }
             ],
             "features": [
              {
               "attributes": {
                "OBJECTID": 1120,
                "DISTRICT": "WESTLA",
                "TILE_NAME": "129B149",
                "TOOLTIP": "District: WESTLA\\nTile: 129B149",
                "NLA_URL": "navigatela/reports/cadastral_map_index.cfm?pk=129B149"
               },
               "geometry": {
                "rings": [
                 [
                  [
                   -118.45870522159555,
                   34.053800267113971
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.44549967992378,
                   34.053813128253687
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.44548872993352,
                   34.045569527150292
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.45869298464309,
                   34.045556665428208
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.45870522159555,
                   34.053800267113971
                  ]
                 ]
                ]
               }
              }
             ]
            }
```

For example you want add arcgis rest api response( esri json)  to feature layer

```
var search_layer_result = JSON.parse(data)

    console.log(search_layer_result)

   // ............ add esri json -> feature layer -> map  ..............


  var featureCollection = {  
                      layerDefinition : search_layer_result,  
                      featureSet : search_layer_result 
                      }; 

 search_result_featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection);  
//var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new esri.Color([255,0,0,0.5]));  
 var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(your_Symbol);  
 search_result_featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);  

 map.addLayer(search_result_featureLayer, your_layer_index_optional);
```