# Feature Layer from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, feature-dataset

I would like to project my shapefile information on the maps. I converted my shapefile into a JSON file. How can use the Json file to create a featurecollection object in the ARCGIS Javascript API. The Json file contains 50 thousand features. Have given a sample set of my feature collection below. I do not want to embed the entire JSON file within the javascript file.

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ROADNAME": "AAA", "LINK_INDEX": 1}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 163.554342, -77.702882 ], [
163.553160, -77.702327 ] ] } } , { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ROADNAME": "KIAN TECK WAY","LINK_INDEX": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 162.527145, -77.686591 ], [
162.522273, -77.686598 ] ] } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some example to show the Json based FeatureCollection as Feature Layer in ARCGIS Javascript API [Json Featurelayer 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/featurelayer-creating-in-javascript-arcgis-api) and [Json To FeatureLayer 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30625/overlaping-graphics-not-visible-in-featurelayer). For showing the 50 Thousand write Handler which returns Json Something like this --->> [Json Handler](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6d28a606369c43fd9a6f929541ae7c93) and give that output of the handler as a string to feature collection.Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

esri json to feature layer

example arcgis rest api request url:

```
http://xxxx.com/xxx/rest/services/Maps_and_Indices/MapServer/2/query?f=pjson&returnCountOnly=false&outFields=*&outSR=4326&where=DISTRICT%20=%20%27129B149%27%20or%20TILE_NAME%20=%20%27129B149%27%20or%20TOOLTIP%20=%20%27129B149%27%20or%20NLA_URL%20=%20%27129B149%27
```

decode URL:

```
 http://xxxx.com/xxx/rest/services/Maps_and_Indices/MapServer/2/query?f=pjson&returnCountOnly=false&outFields=*&outSR=4326&where=DISTRICT = '129B149' or TILE_NAME = '129B149' or TOOLTIP = '129B149' or NLA_URL = '129B149'
```

data: any arcgis rest api return (response)

example (data) :

```
            {
             "displayFieldName": "TILE_NAME",
             "fieldAliases": {
              "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
              "DISTRICT": "DISTRICT",
              "TILE_NAME": "TILE_NAME",
              "TOOLTIP": "TOOLTIP",
              "NLA_URL": "NLA_URL"
             },
             "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
             "spatialReference": {
              "wkid": 4326,
              "latestWkid": 4326
             },
             "fields": [
              {
               "name": "OBJECTID",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
               "alias": "OBJECTID"
              },
              {
               "name": "DISTRICT",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "DISTRICT",
               "length": 16
              },
              {
               "name": "TILE_NAME",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "TILE_NAME",
               "length": 32
              },
              {
               "name": "TOOLTIP",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "TOOLTIP",
               "length": 66
              },
              {
               "name": "NLA_URL",
               "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
               "alias": "NLA_URL",
               "length": 78
              }
             ],
             "features": [
              {
               "attributes": {
                "OBJECTID": 1120,
                "DISTRICT": "WESTLA",
                "TILE_NAME": "129B149",
                "TOOLTIP": "District: WESTLA\\nTile: 129B149",
                "NLA_URL": "navigatela/reports/cadastral_map_index.cfm?pk=129B149"
               },
               "geometry": {
                "rings": [
                 [
                  [
                   -118.45870522159555,
                   34.053800267113971
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.44549967992378,
                   34.053813128253687
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.44548872993352,
                   34.045569527150292
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.45869298464309,
                   34.045556665428208
                  ],
                  [
                   -118.45870522159555,
                   34.053800267113971
                  ]
                 ]
                ]
               }
              }
             ]
            }
```

For example you want add arcgis rest api response( esri json)  to feature layer

```
var search_layer_result = JSON.parse(data)

    console.log(search_layer_result)

   // ............ add esri json -> feature layer -> map  ..............


  var featureCollection = {  
                      layerDefinition : search_layer_result,  
                      featureSet : search_layer_result 
                      }; 

 search_result_featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection);  
//var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new esri.Color([255,0,0,0.5]));  
 var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(your_Symbol);  
 search_result_featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);  

 map.addLayer(search_result_featureLayer, your_layer_index_optional);
```